# symfony OneToMany Form

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am using symfony to build the functions as below:
I have Product and ShippingWays.
One Product could have more ShippingWays and One ShippingWay only match one product.

ProductEntity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ShippingWay",mappedBy="product")
 */
private $shippingWays;
```

ShippingWay Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="shippingWays")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $product;
```

Then I build both the ProductType and  ShippingWayType.

ProductType

```
->add('shippingWays', EntityType::class, array(
            'label'              => ' Shipping Ways',
            'translation_domain' => 'forms',
            'class'              => 'CoreBundle:ShippingWay',
            'choice_label'       => 'name',
            'multiple'           => true,
            'required'           => false,
        ))
```

ProductController

```
 /**
 * @Route("/admin/product/new", name="admin_product_new")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $product = new Product();
    $shippingWay= new ShippingWay();
    $form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product);
    $shippingForm = $this->createForm(ShippingWayType::class, $shippingWay);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($product );
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_product'));
        }
    }
    return(array('form' => $form->createView(),'users'=>$users,'shippingForm '=>$shippingForm ->createView()));
}
```

- I'd like to add/edit the Shipping Way in the product page.
- If there is no suitable shipping ways then I have to create a new one in the product page.
  Something like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdmBB.png)

Currently I have 2 problems:

- How to manage the Shipping way with Form as usual in Product page? Is there a general way to handle the forms under OneToMany & ManyToOne relationships?
- I select Shipping way A when I add Product X, Then I could select Shipping Way A as before when I add product Y. I found that procuct_id with Shipping Way A always be Null.

Could someone give me some suggestions and references?
Thank you very much.

Comment: `then I have to new one in the product page.` - you have to what? Also what do you mean by *manage"? It's pretty broad word. Some code that shows what you're trying to do would be helpful to understand your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jakub. I have update the questions, hope it make more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first problem : In your **ProductType**, you should not use EntityType for ShippingWay as it just display the list of existing entries related to ShippingWay entities.

If you want to add/edit, it would be better to use CollectionType, as specified here: [How to Embed a Collection on a Symfony Form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)

In your case, your **ProductType** would be:

```
->add('shippingWays', CollectionType::class, array(
        'label'              => ' Shipping Ways',
        'translation_domain' => 'forms',
        'entry_type          => 'CoreBundle:ShippingWay',
        'choice_label'       => 'name',
        'allow_add'          => true,
        'allow_delete'       => true
    ))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really help me a lot. Thank you very much again and wish you a great day.